# Defining terminal shortcuts

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal

I use Ubuntu with Gnome.
I carelessly assigned Copy to Ctrl+C (it was Ctrl+Shift+C by default). Now I am unable to use "Kill current process" shortcut. I couldn't change it with "System -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts" since "Kill current process" doesn't appear there. How else can I define the shortcuts or at least make them default?

Comment: As Dave Sherohman points out in xyr answer, there _is no_ "kill current process shortcut".  It's the interrupt signal, which doesn't necessarily kill the current process.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just changing the Copy shortcut to something else?  The normal function of ctrl-C (sending SIGINT to the current process) is provided by your shell, not by Gnome, so I would expect that simply moving the other binding out of the way so that the keystroke can reach your shell should be all that's needed to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You could always hit Alt+F2 and type `killall <name>`
Where `<name>` is the name of the application and can use wildcards. For example, to kill chrome:

```
killall google*
```